I got the next error, when I try to send values from java Netbeans to Mysql: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
I'm trying to send values to the database in SQl using mysql but the error message is

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException* in the line **stmt.setInt(0, id);

I already created the class connect and this is the function to send the values:
private void enviarMySQL() {
    Connect con = new Connect();
    con.ConectarBasedeDatos();
    String query = "INSERT INTO tablebd (id, producto, cantidad, precio) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    DefaultTableModel df = (DefaultTableModel) table4.getModel(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < table4.getRowCount(); i++) {
        // Getting the values
        int id = Integer.parseInt(df.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
        String product = df.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
        double qty = Double.parseDouble(df.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
        double cost= Double.parseDouble(df.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());

        // insert values
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.conexion.prepareStatement(query);
            con.statement.execute("INSERT INTO tablebd (id, product, qty, cost) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");            
            stmt.setInt(0, id);  // first column
            stmt.setString(1, product);  // first column
            stmt.setDouble(2, qty);  // second column
            stmt.setDouble(3, cost);    // 
            stmt.executeUpdate();         // Ejecutamos la sentencia SQL

// Disconnect database
            con.Disconnect();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
        }
    }

and my connection class is as follow:
package App;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Connect {
    public Connection conexion;
    public static Statement statement;
    public ResultSet resultado;

     public void ConectarBasedeDatos(){
        try {
            final String Controlador = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName( Controlador );
            final String url_bd = "jdbc:mysql://----------------";
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url_bd,"----------","-------");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage(), "Excepcion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
     }
     public void DesconectarBasedeDatos() {
        try {
            if (conexion != null ) {
                if(statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                }
                conexion.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage(), "Excepcion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connect con = new Connect();
        con.ConectarBasedeDatos();
    }
     
}

I tried to change the values and only could sent this "INSERT INTO tablebd (id, producto, cantidad, precio) VALUES(0,00,00,00); to the database

Get rid of that custom connection class. It's not helping you

When reporting exceptions, quoting the full stack trace (unless you know which pieces are irrelevant) is pretty much a requirement. The line you mentioned can't itself throw unless prepareStatement() returned null. So it must be in Conexion, we at least need to see where.
